# Form Validator Executed Twice

Tags: ajax, forms, jquery, validation

I have reviewed the database and have not seen how any comments apply specifically to my situation OR I am not genius enough to extend the knowledge.

I am using jQuery Form Validor: formvalidator.net

My head looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../plugins/uniform/css/uniform.default.css" type="text/css"/>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../plugins/uniform/jquery.uniform.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--Monitoring Code-->
<script type="text/javascript" async="async" defer="defer" src="https://chat.banckle.com/chat/visitor.do?dep=72e029a3-64f6-4ffe-b7ea-13c0b3d70a8e"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.1.38/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('input,button,select,textarea').uniform();
    var myLanguage = {
      errorTitle : 'Please try again...',
      requiredFields : 'You have not answered all required fields',
      badTime : 'You have not given a correct time',
      badEmail : 'You have not given a correct e-mail address',
      badTelephone : 'You have not given a correct phone number',
      badSecurityAnswer : 'You have not given a correct answer to the security question',
      badDate : 'You have not given a correct date',
      lengthBadStart : 'You must give an answer between ',
      lengthBadEnd : ' characters',
      lengthTooLongStart : 'You have given an answer longer than ',
      lengthTooShortStart : 'You have given an answer shorter than ',
      notConfirmed : 'Values could not be confirmed',
      badDomain : 'Incorrect domain value',
      badUrl : 'The answer you gave was not a correct URL',
      badCustomVal : 'You gave an incorrect answer',
      badInt : 'The answer you gave was not a correct number',
      badSecurityNumber : 'Your social security number was incorrect',
      badUKVatAnswer : 'Incorrect UK VAT Number',
      badStrength : 'The password isn\'t strong enough',
      badNumberOfSelectedOptionsStart : 'You have to choose at least ',
      badNumberOfSelectedOptionsEnd : ' answers',
      badAlphaNumeric : 'The answer you gave must contain only alphanumeric characters ',
      badAlphaNumericExtra: ' and ',
      wrongFileSize : 'The file you are trying to upload is too large',
      wrongFileType : 'The file you are trying to upload is of wrong type',
      groupCheckedRangeStart : 'Please choose between ',
      groupCheckedTooFewStart : 'Please choose at least ',
      groupCheckedTooManyStart : 'Please choose a maximum of ',
      groupCheckedEnd : ' item(s)'
    };
    $.validate({
        form: '#contact-form',
        validateOnBlur: false,
        errorMessagePosition: 'top',
        scrollToTopOnError: true,
        language: myLanguage,
        onValidate: function() {
            $('.success-form,.form-error').remove();
        },
        onSuccess : function() {
            function processdata(data,success) {
                if (success) {
                    //document.getElementById('contact-form').reset();
                    //alert(data);
                    if (data=="good") {
                        $('#contact-form').prepend("<div class='success-form'>Your message has been sent. You will receive a response within the next 24 hours--or on the next business day.</div>");
                    } else {
                        $('#contact-form').prepend("<div class='form-error'>Unable to contact Genera Safety Inc at this time. Please try again.</div>");
                    }
                }
            }
            var formdata = $('#contact-form').serialize();
            processdata();
            //alert(formdata);
            $.post('process_contact_form.php',formdata,processdata);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The form is submitting twice? Perhaps it is also validating twice?

Anyone see any issues here? I can provide further information if necessary...

Answer (score 1):

The submit event is triggered twice here. I could not find any problem with your code. It seems that the issue is caused by jquery.uniform plugin. You can use the following code to test the plugin alone.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//rawgithub.com/pixelmatrix/uniform/master/jquery.uniform.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
$(function(){
  $("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("form submit event triggered", Date.now());
  })

  $('input,button,select,textarea').uniform();
});
</script>

<form><input type="submit"/></form>
```

By removing `$('input,button,select,textarea').uniform();` from your code, I was able to avoid the double submit issue.

Comment: If I am reading your answer correctly you are suggesting that I should not use the Uniform Plugin. This unfortunately is not the desired solution. I would prefer to continue using it or a functioning substitute. I will however dig in to to the plugin to see if I can pin point there. Thanks for your work on the bug hunt!

Comment: My point here was to highlight the cause of issue. Now you can focus on it either by debugging the plugin yourself or by submitting the issue to Uniform Plugin community.

Comment: absolutely! Thank you.